# Can area of a triangle be found only with angles?

Tags: triangles, area

Let's consider a triangle ΔABC, with angle A = 71°, angle B = 37°, angle C = 72°. So, is this data sufficient to find the area of the ΔABC ? Is there any formula to do so or even a method ?

Comment: Consider an equilateral triangle with side length $1$.  Compare the area of this triangle to an equilateral triangle with side lengths $100000$.  Both triangles have the same trio of angles, but the one clearly has larger area.  Two triangles who have the same angles will be "[*similar*](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/similar-triangles)" but similarity doesn't imply the same area.

Comment: No, consider the dilation by a factor of $3$ on $ABC$. The new triangle has the same angles but different side lengths. Which implies different height and base which means different area.

Comment: In general (like in the title) it depends on geometry. E.g. on a sphere with a given radius it's enough to know the three angles. However the exact values you provided in the question body cannot form a triangle on a sphere. You most likely meant Euclidean geometry. If so, then the accepted answer is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scale the triangle the angles stay the same, while the area is changing.